# Calling a polymer element within a polyment with JSON as parameter

Tags: polymer

I am calling a polymer element within another element. The inner polymer element has a published attribute to which I am binding JSON from the parent polymer. However it is not getting reflected.

```
<polymer-element name="parent-test" attributes="testData">
    <template>

        This is Parent test
        <child-test testdatachild="{{testData}}"></child-test>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('parent-test', {
            testData: [],
            ready: function () {
                debugger;
                this.testData = [1, 2, 3, 4]
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>


<polymer-element name="child-test" attributes="testDataChild">
    <template>
        <!--{{testDataChild}}-->
        <template repeat="{{test in testDataChild}}">
            {{test}}
        </template>


    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('child-test', {
            testDataChild: [],
            ready: function () {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I am not sure what could be the problem here.

Edit:
Seems like I am not having the actual parentContent at the time of generating the child-polymer-element. 
If I assign hardcoded values in ready function for this.parentContent, it doesnt work as well. 
If I assign hardcoded values in create function for this parent.Content, it works. 
So, I am not not sure if this is something related to generating the child polymer element before the values getting binded to parent.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Seems like I am not having the actual parentContent at the time of generating the <child-polymer-element>. If I assign hardcoded values in ready function for this.parentContent, it doesnt work as well. If I assign hardcoded values in create function for this parent.Content, it works. So, I am not not sure if this is something related to generating the child polymer element before the values getting binded to parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your plunk example and get it working without your workaround :
[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUaoSm8njgFfzBVkEcsJ?p=preview)

```
<polymer-element name="child-test" attributes="testdatachild">
<template>
    <br><br>
    In Child el.:
    <br>
    <template repeat="{{test in testdatachild}}">
      {{test}}
      <br>
    </template>


</template>
<script>
    Polymer('child-test', {
        ready: function () {
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
    This is Parent test
    <child-test testdatachild="{{testData}}"></child-test>
  <br>

</template>
<script>                 
    Polymer('parent-test', {
        created: function () {
          this.testData = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        }
    });
</script>
```

The main problem seems to be the order of the code
I guess it works better to first declare the child, then the parent, as the child is used in the parent...
Also, as specified in the polymer documentation :
[polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html)

> Important: For properties that are objects or arrays, you should always initialize the properties in the created callback. If you set the default value directly on the prototype (or on the publish object), you may run into unexpected “shared state” across different instances of the same element.

Comment: Awesome Blastor. Changing the references works. I feel stupid now. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is modified example of you code that works : [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJb9KO7yQiaOPLFYuScX?p=preview)

Why your example is not working, I don't have all answers buy you are right for one:

```
<!-- This won't work cause:
       "Attributes on child-test were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. 
       This may result in incorrect binding types." -->
        This is Parent test
    <child-test testdatachild="{{testData}}"></child-test>
```